How to inference transformer Tflite model Tensorflow?
I want to deploy this model to Raspberry Pi later, but I don't know how to inference the translation using Tflite model. This model is based on this tensorflow tutorial. Here the dataset and tokenizer that I used. Here the model notebook. Please guide me how I can inference this Tflite model? Is the inference process same as normal tf model?
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("translator_id-en")
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
    tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,  # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
    tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS,  # enable TensorFlow ops.
]
# converter._experimental_lower_tensor_list_ops = False
converter.allow_custom_ops = True
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with open("lite.tflite", "wb") as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)

